# PC app launcher alternatives

Tags: windows, launcher, icon

I'm looking for an alternative to having a ton of shortcuts on my desktop / various categorized folders containing shortcuts.

I've tried **Launchy**, and it's alternative **Keypirinha** (with plugins) but I keep forgetting what stuff I have installed / ready to be used
I've seen **RocketDock** and **stacks** but it just doesn't look visually appealing and I'd imagine is also somewhat resource intensive, haven't tried it though.

Obviously I don't forget the apps that I use everyday but it's been a few times that I've searched for an app online only to find I already had it installed and completely forgot because I don't actually see it.

*What I need is a way to easily/constantly see all if not most of the applications I have installed on my PC but not completely clutter my desktop.*

Is there anything that might be a solution?